# Test change of window.location.path in jest? I am using typescript and have a function where the window.location.pathname is changed?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs

I have a react component with code like this

```
 useEffect(() => {
   if(someCondition) {
    window.location.pathname = "/newurl"
   }
 }, [dependency] )
```

I am using Jest and RTL,

I would like to test whether after rendering the component the window.location.pathname = "/newurl"

How can I test this? Currently in jest window.location.pathname returns empty.

I need to use window.location.pathname instead of history.push() since i want the page to refresh when the new url is loaded.

Comment: Can you share the test code?

Comment: Hi did you ever figure this out?